# How would you implement a spinner component that signal the fact an http request is on in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a spinner component that looks like this:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';

class Spinner extends React.Component {

   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         loading: false
      }
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <div className="spinner"
            style={{ display: this.state.loading ? "block" : "none" }}>
            <span>Spinning to signal http loading...</span>
         </div>
      );
   }
}

export default Spinner;
```

Now, I would like to know what is a scalable way of notifying this component that an http call is on/off. Such a notification process should change the `state.loading` to `true|false` and hence display/hide the spinner.

I hope you see what my point is. It is not an obvious problem/solution. Actions triggering stores are issues at every level of the application (nested components) and lifting the state to the main controller component in order to keep track of the http being on/off is just not particularly manageable. In fact that would require passing (from the top component) to every component capable of dispatching an action, a function as a prop that does something like:

```
function() {
   // `this` refers to the main/top component
   this.setState({
     loading: true
   })
}
```

I was also thinking about issuing events from the stores (which are basically `EventEmitter` instances) and listen from the `Spinner` itself to then change the `state.loading` property from there.

But to be honest I am happy with neither the solution. What is in your eyes a very React way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: From Design point of view, you could implement a notification component that listens of the redux or context state and show message and loading state according to the request in process

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify: I am using plain flux. In any case can you show some pseudo code for the concept you expressed there? Thanks